# Is it possible to reject a direct deposit?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, deposits

I received a direct deposit on my bank account (in the US): is it possible to reject it?

Comment: curious: why would you want to?

Comment: Mistakenly getting paid for a service I haven't done: I'd be glad keep the money if there were no tax/visa/etc. issues that could eventually result from it. The amount of money involved is too small for the emitter to care enough about it and for me to take any risk for it.

Comment: You can always send a check back to the payer, with a note explaining why. Your bank will keep a record of that transaction, which should be all the evidence you need that you didn't accept this income. If they decide not to cash the check, that's their decision; it would then have to be considered income and be taxable but that's the only complication that might arise. I think.

Answer (score 3):

Once the payment is in your account, you'll have to contact the person that made it and ask them what to do.  I've had a client pay me twice for the same invoice, and they simply said to keep it and apply the overpay as a credit to my next invoice.  But the bank typically won't reverse the transaction (nor would the sender be able to have the bank reverse it either).  Work it out with the person that deposited the money.

Comment: Since ACH deposits (direct deposits) are made to an account number and routing number (not to a named person), it is easy and quite common for them to be made to the wrong account and the bank will have a way to reverse the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may dispute the transaction as you would any other. Contact your bank for their specific procedures.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Disputing transactions usually is allowed by credit card contracts, I've never heard of being able to dispute an ACH or debit (ATM) transaction.

Comment: From working within a bank for several years.

In general, you have less than 24 hours to dispute ACH transactions (roughly by the time the Fed closes). For debit, policies vary by bank; they aren't standardized by law, as they are for credit transactions.